# Git - All files have lost executable permission after checkout

Tags: linux, git

I wanted to checkout an older commit to my working directory to mess around with something so I did the following command in the root of my repo:

```
git checkout 2aa2c5 .
```

But nothing happened, the # prompt simply came back. I did the command a few more times, but nothing seemed to happen. I then did:

```
git status
```

Which showed that I was still on `master`. I then did:

```
git checkout master
```

As I wasn't sure what was happening and just wanted to get back to where I was. It came back with `Already on master`

However now my website is not accessible, every single file now seems to have the permission 644? I am really not sure what has happened? It looks like although my original attempt to checkout a commit didn't do anything, it has messed with my file permissions, and/or file ownership.

**UPDATE: I don't think it is the permission that is the problem. I think the problem is that all the files have changed to root for the owner and group? I was logged in as root when I did the checkout, will that have caused this?**

I am new to git and Linux file permission in general, if anyone could shed some light on this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: I don't think it is the permission that is the problem. I think the problem is that all the files have changed to root for the owner and group? I was logged in as root when I did the checkout, will that have caused this?

Comment: `644` is correct for normal files (i.e. html files, images). Look into the error logs of your web server to see why your site is no longer accessible. Folders should have execute permission but probably `750` instead of `755` since the latter would give access to anyone.

Comment: Please edit your original question.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Thanks, please see my update above your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions and ownership are really critical for web servers. If you get this wrong, the wrong people (= crackers) can read or modify your files. So make sure you understand what you're doing.

As a rule of thumb, never work as `root`. One silly mistake (like a flacky mouse that cut&pastes too much) can cost you the work of many hours.

In your case, it seems that the ownership of the files was changed. To fix this, you will have to delete all the files (as root; be **careful** - if you make a mistake, a lot more that you might ever want will be gone!)

Try to keep the Git repo (i.e. delete everything except for the `.git` folder) but I fear that running `git` as root has already messed with some permissions in that folder as well.

So your best bet might be to delete the whole tree (including the .git folder) and clone it again with the correct user.

Related:

- http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Security/Quick_and_Dirty_Guide_to_Linux_File_Permissions

Comment: `sudo chown -Rc $UID .git/`    should fix that folder

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Just to be clear on what you are suggesting. I should remove/delete the entire contents of my working direcotry, including the .git folder. Then clone it again from bitbucket using the correct user (not root)?

Comment: @superphonic: That's the most simple solution. You can also try to fix permissions using `chmod(1)` and `chown(1)` but other than being a good exercise, I don't see a point (unless your project takes half an hour to clone).

Comment: @user1281385: +1 Yes. Unless he did something else (like committing) which would have written the root user into one of the files.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I think removing everything and starting again is the best solution. I also use AWS tools to push commits to my Amazon cloud service, I fear the .aws folder may have also got screwed up, so starting from scratch is the safest solution I feel..